# Consul servers: 1/3 is connected but does not have a leader

Tags: consul

I have a 3 server Consul setup with other nodes as clients

2/3 of the Consul servers respond successfully with

```
root@ewr70:~# consul operator raft list-peers
Node   ID                                    Address               State     Voter  RaftProtocol
ewr70  823e8c0e-fea2-be32-4c0d-bd06437f14e1  IP:8300  follower  true   3
ewp1   a733c143-4702-30cb-5ff3-6094b108ea06  IP:8300     follower  true   3
la452  ad4e15ac-1d73-00b8-cce7-cd5d5a2254a4  IP:8300   leader    true   3
```

```
root@la452:~# consul operator raft list-peers
Node   ID                                    Address               State     Voter  RaftProtocol
ewr70  823e8c0e-fea2-be32-4c0d-bd06437f14e1  IP:8300  follower  true   3
ewp1   a733c143-4702-30cb-5ff3-6094b108ea06  IP:8300     follower  true   3
la452  ad4e15ac-1d73-00b8-cce7-cd5d5a2254a4  IP:8300   leader    true   3
```

One of them says no cluster leader

```
root@ewp1:~# consul operator raft list-peers
Error getting peers: Failed to retrieve raft configuration: Unexpected response code: 500 (No cluster leader)
```

The server failing to `list-peers` also displays members of the cluster so it acts like it is working except for this cluster leader problem

What I have tried doing:

- Restarting consul servers
- Creating peers.json on all servers and restarting
- `consul server join IP`

Here are some parts of the consul log output which I think may help understand after executing `systemctl restart consul`

```
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: ==> Starting Consul agent...
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:               Version: 'IPHIDDEN.2'
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:            Build Date: '2022-09-20 20:30:07 +0000 UTC'
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:               Node ID: 'a733c143-4702-30cb-5ff3-6094b108ea06'
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:             Node name: 'ewp1'
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:            Datacenter: 'proxies' (Segment: '<all>')
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:                Server: true (Bootstrap: true)
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:           Client Addr: [IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: -1, DNS: 8600)
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:          Cluster Addr: IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:     Gossip Encryption: true
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:      Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:             HTTPS TLS: Verify Incoming: false, Verify Outgoing: false, Min Version: TLSv1_2
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:              gRPC TLS: Verify Incoming: false, Min Version: TLSv1_2
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]:      Internal RPC TLS: Verify Incoming: false, Verify Outgoing: false (Verify Hostname: false), Min Version: TLSv1_2
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.env, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl.64IPHIDDEN2-09-22@16:35:16~, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent: bootstrap = true: do not enable unless necessary
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent.auto_config: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.env, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent.auto_config: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl.64IPHIDDEN2-09-22@16:35:16~, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent.auto_config: bootstrap = true: do not enable unless necessary
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.raft: starting restore from snapshot: id=5-368711-1668054243884 last-index=368711 last-term=5 size-in-bytes=28562
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.raft: snapshot restore progress: id=5-368711-1668054243884 last-index=368711 last-term=5 size-in-bytes=28562 read-bytes=28562 percent-complete=IPHIDDEN%
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.raft: restored from snapshot: id=5-368711-1668054243884 last-index=368711 last-term=5 size-in-bytes=28562
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.raft: initial configuration: index=1 servers="[{Suffrage:Voter ID:823e8c0e-fea2-be32-4c0d-bd06437f14e1 Address:IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300} {Suffrage:Voter ID:a733c143-4702-30cb-5ff3-6094b108ea06 Address:IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300} {Suffrage:Voter ID:ad4e15ac-1d73-00b8-cce7-cd5d5a2254a4 Address:IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300}]"
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.raft: entering follower state: follower="Node at IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300 [Follower]" leader-address= leader-id=
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: ewp1.proxies IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: Attempting re-join to previously known node: hetz-5.hetz: IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8302
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: ewp1 IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.router: Initializing LAN area manager
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.lan: serf: Attempting re-join to previously known node: securepri9245: IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8301
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server: Adding LAN server: server="ewp1 (Addr: tcp/IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300) (DC: proxies)"
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.autopilot: reconciliation now disabled
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent: [core]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {proxies-IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300 ewp1 <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:0->IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8300: operation was canceled". Reconnecting...
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=ewp1.proxies area=wan
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8600 network=tcp
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8600 network=udp
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8600 network=udp
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8600 network=tcp
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Starting server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8500 network=tcp protocol=http
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Starting server: address=IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN:8500 network=tcp protocol=http
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: started state syncer
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Consul agent running!
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Retry join is supported for the following discovery methods: cluster=LAN discovery_methods="aliyun aws azure digitalocean gce k8s linode mdns os packet scaleway softlayer tencentcloud triton vsphere"
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Joining cluster...: cluster=LAN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: (LAN) joining: lan_addresses=[proxies-3.datacenter.HOSTHIDDEN.net, proxies-1.datacenter.HOSTHIDDEN.net]
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Retry join is supported for the following discovery methods: cluster=WAN discovery_methods="aliyun aws azure digitalocean gce k8s linode mdns os packet scaleway softlayer tencentcloud triton vsphere"
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: Joining cluster...: cluster=WAN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent: (WAN) joining: wan_addresses=[24.services.HOSTHIDDEN.net]
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: 24-IPHIDDENshells IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: hetz-new-nomad-pink.hetz IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=24-IPHIDDENshells area=wan
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: hetz-5.hetz IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=hetz-new-nomad-pink.hetz area=wan
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server.serf.wan: serf: EventMemberJoin: 24-IPHIDDENshells IPHIDDEN.IPHIDDEN
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [INFO]  agent.server: Handled event for server in area: event=member-join server=hetz-5.hetz area=wan
Nov 10 11:13:33 ewp1 consul[821921]: 2022-11-10T19:13:IPHIDDEN+0800 [WARN]  agent.server.memberlist.wan: memberlist: Refuting an alive message for 'ewp1.proxies'
```

Does anyone know what course of action I need to take to get this server behaving?